# Convert an array string into a 3D array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a string from a file and I'm trying to convert it into a 3d array.

```
[[[0.43096440627115085, -0.8577107283236622, -0.28036045913403573], [-0.4082482904638634, 0.09175170953613587, -0.9082482904638631], [0.8047378541243648, 0.5058793634016807, -0.31061721752604615]], [131.17115021913514, 164.44788458945936, -1692.8571428571427]][[[0.43096440627115085, -0.8577107283236622, -0.28036045913403573], [-0.4082482904638634, 0.09175170953613587, -0.9082482904638631], [0.8047378541243648, 0.5058793634016807, -0.31061721752604615]], [131.17115021913514, 164.44788458945936, -1692.8571428571427]][[[0.43096440627115085, -0.8577107283236622, -0.28036045913403573], [-0.4082482904638634, 0.09175170953613587, -0.9082482904638631], [0.8047378541243648, 0.5058793634016807, -0.31061721752604615]], [131.17115021913514, 164.44788458945936, -1692.8571428571427]][[[0.43096440627115085, -0.8577107283236622, -0.28036045913403573], [-0.4082482904638634, 0.09175170953613587, -0.9082482904638631], [0.8047378541243648, 0.5058793634016807, -0.31061721752604615]], [131.17115021913514, 164.44788458945936, -1692.8571428571427]][[[0.43096440627115085, -0.8577107283236622, -0.28036045913403573], [-0.4082482904638634, 0.09175170953613587, -0.9082482904638631], [0.8047378541243648, 0.5058793634016807, -0.31061721752604615]], [131.17115021913514, 164.44788458945936, -1692.8571428571427]][[[0.43096440627115085, -0.8577107283236622, -0.28036045913403573], [-0.4082482904638634, 0.09175170953613587, -0.9082482904638631], [0.8047378541243648, 0.5058793634016807, -0.31061721752604615]], [131.17115021913514, 164.44788458945936, -1692.8571428571427]][[[0.43096440627115085, -0.8577107283236622, -0.28036045913403573], [-0.4082482904638634, 0.09175170953613587, -0.9082482904638631], [0.8047378541243648, 0.5058793634016807, -0.31061721752604615]], [131.17115021913514, 164.44788458945936, -1692.8571428571427]][[[0.43096440627115085, -0.8577107283236622, -0.28036045913403573], [-0.4082482904638634, 0.09175170953613587, -0.9082482904638631], [0.8047378541243648, 0.5058793634016807, -0.31061721752604615]], [131.17115021913514, 164.44788458945936, -1692.8571428571427]]
```

Everything I've tried has come up short.

```
with open(output_dir/f"{input_reg}.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8') as file1:
    Fa = file1.read()
    Fa = np.frombuffer(Fa, dtype=float)
    Fd = json.loads(Fa)
```

Comment: `json.loads(f'[{s.replace("]][[[", "]], [[[")}]')`, by the way, the result is not a regular 3d array.

Comment: @MechanicPig can you please be a bit more specific. Am I using np.frombuffer correctly here?

Answer (score -2):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to convert string to array.

Sample code:

```py
s = '[[[0, 1], [0, 2]], [[0,3], [0,4]]]'
x = np.array(ast.literal_eval(s))
print(x)
```

Result:

```
[[[0 1] 
  [0 2]]

 [[0 3]
  [0 4]]]
```

Comment: If an eval shortcut is used, use `ast.literal_eval` to only allow literals and not any arbitrary python code.